# Unable to run unit test cases

Tags: java, spring-boot, junit5, junit-jupiter

I am writing test cases for my project using Junit5, when I run a test cases all the test cases passes, but some of them gives me below error in console

```
WARNING: TestEngine with ID 'junit-jupiter' failed to execute tests
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: junit/framework/ComparisonFailure
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit5.runner.JUnit5TestListener.getFailedComparison(JUnit5TestListener.java:133)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit5.runner.JUnit5TestListener.notifyIfNotSuccessful(JUnit5TestListener.java:89)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit5.runner.JUnit5TestListener.executionFinished(JUnit5TestListener.java:71)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.TestExecutionListenerRegistry$CompositeTestExecutionListener.lambda$executionFinished$3(TestExecutionListenerRegistry.java:77)
    at java.util.ArrayList.forEach(Unknown Source)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.TestExecutionListenerRegistry.notifyTestExecutionListeners(TestExecutionListenerRegistry.java:51)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.TestExecutionListenerRegistry.access$100(TestExecutionListenerRegistry.java:27)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.TestExecutionListenerRegistry$CompositeTestExecutionListener.executionFinished(TestExecutionListenerRegistry.java:77)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.ExecutionListenerAdapter.executionFinished(ExecutionListenerAdapter.java:56)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.reportCompletion(NodeTestTask.java:138)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.execute(NodeTestTask.java:79)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.submit(SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.java:32)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.HierarchicalTestExecutor.execute(HierarchicalTestExecutor.java:57)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.HierarchicalTestEngine.execute(HierarchicalTestEngine.java:51)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.execute(DefaultLauncher.java:170)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.execute(DefaultLauncher.java:154)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.execute(DefaultLauncher.java:90)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit5.runner.JUnit5TestReference.run(JUnit5TestReference.java:89)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.TestExecution.run(TestExecution.java:41)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:541)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:763)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.run(RemoteTestRunner.java:463)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.main(RemoteTestRunner.java:209)
```

for e.g.

```
Mockito.verify(exportFile, Mockito.times(1)).exportCsvFile(Mockito.anyList(), Mockito.anyString());
Mockito.verify(exportFile, Mockito.times(2)).exportCsvFile(Mockito.anyList(), Mockito.anyString());
Mockito.verify(exportFile, Mockito.times(3)).exportCsvFile(Mockito.anyList(), Mockito.anyString();
```

Every time test case passes, but for second and third case I am seeing `java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: junit/framework/ComparisonFailure`

Below is how my pom looks like:

```
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
            <!-- exclude junit 4 -->
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>junit</groupId>
                    <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        <!-- junit 5 -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit-jupiter-api</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit-jupiter-engine</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
```

Below is how my test class looks like (provided necessary part of the class).

```
public class AccountServiceTest {
    AccountService AccountService;
    @Mock
    ExportFile exportFile;

    @BeforeEach
    public void init() {
        MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this);
        accountService = new AccountService(exportFile);
    }
    @Test
    public void testFileExport() {
        accountService.process(partner.getName());
        Mockito.verify(exportFile).exportCsvFile(Mockito.anyList(), Mockito.anyString());
    }
}
```

Comment: First the only dependency you need in your project is spring-boot-starter-test since it will bring you JUnit 5 (which include JUnit 4), Mockito, AssertJ, etc...
Please provide your class test

Comment: @Fabien My spring-boot-starter-test version is `2.1.6.RELEASE`, when I remove other dependencies unable to find `@Test` and `@BeforeEach`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you can upgrade your spring-boot-starter-test to at least `2.2.0.RELEASE` it will bring you JUnit 5 (the exclusion is also not necessary if you want run JUnit4 and JUnit5 tests at the same time). Using only spring boot starter dependencies is a good way to handle incompatible version issue between dependencies as spring boot manages that for you.

If you want run a test with JUnit5 and Mockito, your class should look like this (the object you want to test is annotated with `@InjectMocks` and it's dependency you want mock with `@Mock` and the class test with `@ExtendWith(MockitoExtension.class)`)  :

```
import org.junit.jupiter.api.Test;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.extension.ExtendWith;
import org.mockito.InjectMocks;
import org.mockito.Mock;
import org.mockito.Mockito;
import org.mockito.junit.jupiter.MockitoExtension;

@ExtendWith(MockitoExtension.class)
public class AccountServiceTest {

    @Mock
    ExportFile exportFile;

    @InjectMocks
    AccountService accountService;

    @Test
    public void testFileExport() {
        accountService.process("");
        Mockito.verify(exportFile).exportCsvFile(Mockito.anyList(), Mockito.anyString());
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks @Fabien, In a way your answer helped me fix the issue. For me removing exclusion section resolved the issue.